# How do I pass the value of a global variable to all the classes in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, global-variables

I am developing an ATM simulation tkinter app. Firstly, I created arrays of account no., pin no., etc. to store predefined values. Then, after getting the account no. and pin no. from user on the start page, I am storing the value of the index in a global variable x to keep track of other information like balance, etc. But I am unable to access the value of this global variable in every class. Its by default set to -1 and after me changing to the index of the input values, its still is -1. This is the global variable and array structure:

```
accountNo = ['xyz','abc','pqr']
pinNo = ['1234','7893','4423']
current_balance = [1000,2000,5000]
phnNo = ['1235679870','4563798027','6783409820']
Name = ['alice','bob','candice']
x = -1
y = -1
```

Now, on the start page, after getting input from the user I am changing the values of the global variables x and y as:

```
def check_password():
        account = my_password.get()
        pin = my_pin.get()

        global x
        global y

        x = accountNo.index(account)
        y = pinNo.index(pin)
        if account in accountNo and pin in pinNo:
            if x==y:
               my_password.set('') 
               my_pin.set('')
               incorrect_password_label['text']=''
               controller.show_frame('MenuPage')

            else:
                incorrect_password_label['text']='Invalid Pin or Account No.'
               
        else:
            incorrect_password_label['text']='Incorrect Password'
            
    enter_button = tk.Button(self,
                                                 text='Enter',
                                                 command=check_password,
                                                 relief='raised',
                                                 borderwidth = 3,
                                                 width=40,
                                                 height=3)
    enter_button.pack(pady=10)

    incorrect_password_label = tk.Label(self,
                                                                    text='',
                                                                    font=('orbitron',13),
                                                                    fg='black',
                                                                    bg='#A5A3A3',
                                                                    anchor='n')
    incorrect_password_label.pack(fill='both',expand=True)
```

This is the structure of the main class of this tkinter app:

```py
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.shared_data = {'Balance':tk.IntVar()}

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, MenuPage, WithdrawPage, DepositPage, BalancePage,ChangePin,Details):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
```

Now, I want to use this variable x in other classes too, but the value is not changing globally and it's showing -1 everywhere outside of the check_password() function. **simply I want to access the global variable x everywhere after getting its value changed.** what should I do ?